# SQL How to return one ID in a select distinct query with multiple IDs in a table while still returning all other IDs as well (not just the top row)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL server.
The following query produces a table much like this:

```
idnumber | checkID | taskID | status
1001     | 9000    | 410    | Approved
1001     | 9001    | 410    | Approved
1001     | 9002    | 410    | Approved
1201     | 9100    | 430    | Approved
1201     | 9101    | 430    | Approved
```

...and what I need is the query to just return one of the idnumbers, regardless of the other data (so that only one of the idnumbers is "approved" but not the others).

The result I would like would be similar to:
    idnumber | checkID | taskID | status
    1001     | 9000    | 410    | Approved
    1201     | 9100    | 430    | Approved

My query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT viewTable.idnumber
              , viewTable.checkID
              , viewTable.taskID
              , 'Approved' AS status
FROM    viewTable

INNER JOIN anotherTable
    ON viewTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

INNER JOIN someOtherTable
ON someOtherTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

WHERE anotherTable.CODE = 'DesiredCode'
```

More about this issue:
I have a specific value I am looking for in anotherTable.CODE, and only want to "approve" that specific code. The query above approves anything with an idnumber returned.

Comment: Well it truly returns distinct records. Don't include the other columns that make it non-distinct. And/Or use a join or subquery to get those columns separately, if needed.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: Just remove checkid and taskid from your select statement!!

Comment: you can use top or limit  depend of the db you are using

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function such as `max` or `min` to only be interested in unique values from one column:

```
SELECT viewTable.idnumber
              , MAX(viewTable.checkID) AS checkID
              , MAX(viewTable.taskID) AS taskID
              , 'Approved' AS status
FROM    viewTable

INNER JOIN anotherTable
    ON viewTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

INNER JOIN someOtherTable
ON someOtherTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

WHERE anotherTable.CODE = 'DesiredCode'
GROUP BY viewTable.idnumber
```

Comment: @scaisEdge did OP mean one IDNumber for each taskID, not one TaskID for each IDnumber?

Comment: i don't kown what the OP  mean i was looking only at the sample provided  .

Comment: I am just needing one IDnumber regardless of any taskID. I am wanting to only "approve" just one of the tasks for every IDNumber.

Comment: One task per IDNumber should be solved with the answer I gave.

Comment: That did it! I still needed the column names so I edited the post to add "AS checkID" and "AS taskID."  Thank you all very much! I apologize for the wording of my original post, but we all got through it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is just use TOP 1  for get the firts row

```
  SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT viewTable.idnumber
                , viewTable.checkID
                , viewTable.taskID
                , 'Approved' AS status
  FROM    viewTable

  INNER JOIN anotherTable
      ON viewTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

  INNER JOIN someOtherTable
  ON someOtherTable.idnumber = anotherTable.idnumber

  WHERE anotherTable.CODE = 'DesiredCode'
```

eventually with a proper order by

Comment: That will only return one row from the viewTable. Which is answering my question. I didn't phrase it well...

Comment: I don't understand you comment  .. my answer  is what you are looking for or you need  more?